# How to generate all possible combinations with delimiter

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I use this code `=INDEX(FLATTEN(A2:A4&" "&TRANSPOSE(B2:B4)))` to generate all possible combinations from range A2:B4.

It works fine, but I need to add a 'comma' between the values. I mean that where I get 'a1' I need to it to be 'a,1'.

Take a look a this document to see what I mean: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eOG7m4s0zvk-2m7Uaj9XACYOPS_QTs2p9i-TMHeqyi0/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: Use the concatenating parameter as such `&" ,"&` in place of the current version of `&" "&`

Comment: Can you move this comment to an answer to accept it? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Use the concatenating parameter as such `&" ,"&` in place of the current version of `&" "&`*